# Task in Android Studio project is failing with getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8888 8888:80 error

Tags: android-studio, npm, apollo, codegen

My project is failing because one of the tasks in  the project is failing. I don't think its the code since the project is successfully building in another machine.

I have tried the following:
1> making sure there is no proxy setting. Its currently set to "Automatically detect settings"
2> Making sure the environment variables do not have any specific "HTTP_PROXY" or "HTTPS_PROXY" setting. 
3> Uninstalling nodejs from machine. 
4> Restarting machine.

Error message I am getting is:

> Task :location:installApolloCodegen FAILED

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\<Project_Name>\\common\\location\\.gradle\\nodejs\\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\<user_name>\\<project_name>\\common\\location\\.gradle\\nodejs\\node-v6.7.0-win-x64\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "apollo-codegen@0.19.1" "--save" "--save-exact"
npm ERR! node v6.7.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, 
cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 8888 8888:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network 
settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<user_name>\ 
<project_name>\common\location\build\apollo-codegen\npm-debug.log
```

Appreciate any help/debugging tips. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I uninstalled and re-installed nodejs. After restarting machine, my project now builds.